Cyrillic to upper function in fasm on linux
I have a part of code that compares 2 bytes in ax like one unicode UTF-8 symbol and comverts it's to upper one, but amid russian alphabet function dont works.
; first byte starts with 110
; and second with 10
; like 110 10001 10 010001
; so 10001010001 is 1105 or 0451 

cmp ax, 1101000110010001b ; ё russian this one is a bit not in the range of others
je convert_yo

cmp ax, 1101000110001111b ; я russian, 1071 or 042F in unicode
ja loop_next ; skip

cmp ax, 1101000010101111b ; Я russian, 1103 or 044F in unicode
ja strochnaya


; just add 2 bytes to rdi and skip em
add rdi, 2
jmp loop_string ; begin new itteration of entire function

strochnaya:
   sub ax, word 20h ; -32 because in russian alphabet 33 and -1 ё = 32 symbols
   jmp end_russian_symbol

convert_yo:
   mov ax, 1101000010000001b ; Ё

end_russian_symbol:
; also dont know why just ax doesnt work
; mov word [rdi], ax
    mov byte [rdi], ah
    mov byte [rdi + 1], al
    add rdi, 2         ; add 2 bytes
    jmp loop_string ; begin new itteration of entire function

Of course there can be i believe solution like with ё but for every symbol but its not human to do so.

Is this UTF-8 or UTF-16?  I'm guessing UTF-8, but you never say that anywhere.  There are multiple ways to serialize unicode.  Your two byte store are the opposite endianness from what mov [rdi], ax does.  How are you loading AX in the first place?  If you have the higher address in AL, then your store has to undo the byte-swapping.

@PeterCordes Yes it's UTF-8. First byte with 110 at begin if it's two byte character in AH mov ah, [rdi] and second with 10 in AL mov al, [rdi + 1]. So of AH and AL I have just AX to compare to bytes in binary view instead of comparing them by one. All checks of them to be valid two byte character are not in the example but before. I now tried it and it works but for every word that starts with unicode it trims first letter.

AH is the High half of AX, and x86 is little-endian.  So you are loading them byte-swapped vs. what you'd get from mov ax, [rdi] (or better, movzx eax, word [rdi] to avoid a false dependency.)  Byte-swap your constants and your code can just work with word loads and word stores.

@PeterCordes not quite understand why byte-swap anything if it works absolutely correctly with mov byte [rdi], ah and mov byte [rdi + 1], al. Also isnt i'm comparing AX just to bynary numbers that would look so in big-endian? Isnt UTF-8 works in big-endian? I found р(russian) synbol as 0x0440 in big-endian so it 110 10001 10 000000 also in big-endian and it works. The problem only in loading AX into [rdi] in one mov instaead of AH and AL by one that both together consecutively itself are AX.

I tried bswap eax then mov word [rdi], ax and it still works but trims last letter, i even more confused about how it really works.

Your current code loads 2 bytes from memory into AX as if it was a big-endian 16-bit integer into AX, by loading the first byte into AH and the second into AL, same as you'd get from movbe ax, [rdi] (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movbe).  Your constants match this.  If you want to avoid byte-swapping at run-time with your loads and stores (so you could use mov [rdi], ax instead of movbe [rdi], ax or rol ax, 8 / mov [rdi], ax or two stores), you need to byte-swap your constants to match loading with movzx eax, word [rdi].

bswap eax reverse the whole 4-byte register, so AX takes its value from the high 2 bytes of  the input.  The bytes you want are in the bottom.  You want bswap ax but it doesn't exist, so actually use rol ax, 8.  (Or swap your constants instead of swapping bytes around at run-time.  Including sub eax, 0x20 becoming sub eax, 0x20 << 8; I'm assuming that like ASCII, that just clears a bit, no carry propagation to higher bits.  Since that wouldn't work across bytes of UTF-8 anyway.  So you could use btr, or btc eax, 5+8 to flip that bit (like XOR with 1<< (5+8) but more compact)

the hell of unicode
;110 10000 10 111111 ; п
;110 10000 11 000000 ; no more unicode, cuz second byte doesnt starts with 10
;110 10001 10 000000 ; р

so
strochnaya:
cmp ax, 1101000010111111b ; п 
ja more_tan_p_strochnaya

simple_strochnaya:
    sub ax, word 20h ; just -32
    jmp end_russian_symbol

more_tan_p_strochnaya:
    sub ax, word 0xE0  ; 225 because 193 for save 10 of second byte and + 32 = 225
    jmp end_russian_symbol

